# Kill concurrent materialized view refresh PID

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, materialized-view, kill

Concurrent refreshes of materialized views don't have a record in `pg_stat_activity`, other than the initial (~immediately completing) query to start them.

Is there some other way to obtain the PID, in order to `perform pg_terminate_backend(pid)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not true.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW slow AS
SELECT i,
       pg_sleep(1) IS NULL AS no
FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS i;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON slow (i);

REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY slow;
```

That statement does **not** complete immediately, but hangs until the materialized view is refreshed.

Then, while the statement is running, in another session:

```
SELECT pid, state, query FROM pg_stat_activity ;

  pid  | state  |                      query                       
-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------
 12618 |        | 
 12620 |        | 
 13049 | active | REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY slow ;
 13032 | active | SELECT pid, state, query FROM pg_stat_activity ;
 12616 |        | 
 12615 |        | 
 12617 |        | 
(7 rows)

SELECT pg_cancel_backend(13049);

 pg_cancel_backend 
-------------------
 t
```

The statement is canceled. In the first session, I see:

```
ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
```

Perhaps you are confused by the fact that the `query` column in `pg_stat_activity` does *not* only show the current query, but **the latest query that was run in that session**.  So if the `state` is `idle`, then the statement is done and the materialized view is already refreshed. Then of course canceling the query has no effect.